# Allow user with ANY password IF coming from a specific IP address

Tags: apache, authentication, reverse-proxy

We have an HTTP service behind an Apache reverse proxy that needs to be accessed by a script running on a different server from a particular IP address in order to impersonate any user.

The Apache reverse proxy authenticates users via the LDAP server and passes the user name via a special X-Remote-User header to the above mentioned HTTP service.

This remote script doesn't know the passwords of any users, so Apache should let it access the resource without a password, any password, or even one-off password for all accounts. Anynomous access is not a solution as the script needs to actually impersonate a user, i.e. Apache has to pass the user name via the extra X-Remote-User HTTP header. Normally, this service is accessed by users who provide both user name and password when accessed from open internet. I cannot change the actual HTTP service, only the Apache reverse proxy to which end users connect.

Is this possible? I've tried many configurations with  <Require ip 1.2.3.4>   but none worked, ie. if the script accessed the HTTP service from this IP address, it would get 403 etc, probably because Apache doesn't even pass the user name if the request comes from 1.2.3.4.

An ideal solution would be configuration that asks for user name and password but lets the user supply any password if it comes from a particular IP address. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the solution in the end was quite elegant:

```
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User "expr=%{HTTP:Authorization}"
RequestHeader edit X-Remote-User "^Basic (.*)$" $1
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User "expr=%{unbase64:%{HTTP:X-Remote-User}}"
RequestHeader edit X-Remote-User "(.*):.*$" $1

<RequireAny>
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
</RequireAny>
```

This will pass the credentials - eliminating the password - to the backend server when the service is being accessed from the IP address given. The script running on 1.2.3.4 can then impersonate any user it wants.